# grunt usemin has no input files

Tags: input, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I am new to grunt and had created a angularjs project, which I want to build with.
My useminPrepare:js shows an output like: 
Looking for build script HTML comment blocks

Configuration is now:

concat:
  {}

uglify:
  {}

cssmin:
  { options: { root: ../' } }

autoprefixer:
  {}

Running "useminPrepare:js" (useminPrepare) task

So it seems to have no input.

Can you please give me a hint, how I can configure the input.

My **project layout** is:

- src/main/webapp/web
- src/main/webapp/mobile
- src/main/webapp/common,

whereas I have to angularjs client's, one with bootstrap for web and one with ionic for mobile and I want to share all the services and a part of the controllers. 
web and mobile contain both a Gruntfile and shall be two client projects. 
Is this an acceptable way to structure my use case?

The **client projects** are structured like:
indexmobile.html
indexweb.html

- [common]
- [mobile]
- [web]

  - assets

    - images/
    - bla.png
    - styles/
    - bla.css
  - components

    - comp1

      - bla.controller.js
      - bla.html
    - comp2

whereas the common project contains all the shared things (services...)

My **Gruntfile** of web is e.g.:

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');
var proxySnippet = require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest;

var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var parseVersionFromPomXml = function () {
    var version;
    var pomXml = fs.readFileSync('../../../../pom.xml', "utf8");
    parseString(pomXml, function (err, result) {
        version = result.project.version[0];
    });
    return version;
};

var useminAutoprefixer = {
    name: 'autoprefixer',
    createConfig: require('grunt-usemin/lib/config/cssmin').createConfig
};

  module.exports = function (grunt) {
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
        yeoman: {
            // configurable paths
            app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
            dist: 'build/dist'
        },
        watch: {
            bower: {
                files: ['bower.json'],
                tasks: ['wiredep']
            },
            ngconstant: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'pom.xml'],
                tasks: ['ngconstant:dev']
            },
            styles: {
                files: ['assets/styles/**/*.css']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: 35729
                },
                files: [
                    '**/*.html',
                    '**/*.json',
                    '{.tmp/,}assets/styles/**/*.css',
                    '{.tmp/,}scripts/**/*.js',
                    'assets/images/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ]
            }
        },

        wiredep: {
            app: {
                src: ['../indexweb.html'],
                exclude: [/angular-i18n/, /swagger-ui/]
            },
            test: {
                src: '../../../test/javascript/web/karma.conf.js',
                exclude: [/angular-i18n/, /swagger-ui/, /angular-scenario/],
                ignorePath: /\.\.\/\.\.\//, // remove ../../ from paths of injected javascripts
                devDependencies: true,
                fileTypes: {
                    js: {
                        block: /(([\s\t]*)\/\/\s*bower:*(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/\/\s*endbower)/gi,
                        detect: {
                            js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
                        },
                        replace: {
                            js: '\'{{filePath}}\','
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        connect: {
            proxies: [
                {
                    context: '/api',
                    host: 'localhost',
                    port: 8080,
                    https: false,
                    changeOrigin: false
                },
                {
                    context: '/metrics',
                    host: 'localhost',
                    port: 8080,
                    https: false,
                    changeOrigin: false
                },
                {
                    context: '/dump',
                    host: 'localhost',
                    port: 8080,
                    https: false,
                    changeOrigin: false
                },
                {
                    context: '/health',
                    host: 'localhost',
                    port: 8080,
                    https: false,
                    changeOrigin: false
                },
                {
                    context: '/configprops',
                    host: 'localhost',
                    port: 8080,
                    https: false,
                    changeOrigin: false
                },
                {
                    context: '/beans',
                    host: 'localhost',
                    port: 8080,
                    https: false,
                    changeOrigin: false
                },
                {
                    context: '/api-docs',
                    host: 'localhost',
                    port: 8080,
                    https: false,
                    changeOrigin: false
                },
                {
                    context: '/console',
                    host: 'localhost',
                    port: 8080,
                    https: false,
                    changeOrigin: false
                }
            ],
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                hostname: '0.0.0.0',
                livereload: 35729
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '.'
                    ],
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            proxySnippet,
                            connect.static('.tmp'),
                            connect.static('.')
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    port: 9001,
                    base: [
                        '.tmp',
                        'test',
                        '.'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
            },
            all: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                'app.js',
                '../common/**/*.js',
                'components/**/*.js'
            ]
        },
        concat: {

        },
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/**/*.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/styles/**/*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/images/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/fonts/*'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        useminPrepare: {
            html: ['bower_components/**/*.html', 'components/**/*.html', 'swagger-ui/**/*.html'],
            js: ['components/**/*.js', '../common/components/**/*.js'],
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                flow: {
                    html: {
                        steps: {
                            js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
                            css: ['cssmin', useminAutoprefixer] // Let cssmin concat files so it corrects relative paths to fonts and images
                        },
                        post: {}
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/styles/**/*.css'],
            js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/components/**/*.js'],
            options: {
                assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/styles', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/images', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/fonts'],
                patterns: {
                    js: [
                        [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
                    ]
                },
                dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
            }
        },
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'assets/images',
                    src: '**/*.{jpg,jpeg}', 
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/images'
                }]
            }
        },
        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'assets/images',
                    src: '**/*.svg',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/images'
                }]
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            options: {
                root: '../' 
            }
        },
        ngtemplates: {
            dist: {
                cwd: '.',
                src: ['components/**/*.html', '../common/components/**/*.html'],
                dest: '.tmp/templates/templates.js',
                options: {
                    module: 'rupcomApp',
                    usemin: 'app.js',
                    htmlmin: {
                        removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                        collapseWhitespace: true,
                        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                        conservativeCollapse: true,
                        removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                        useShortDoctype: true,
                        removeEmptyAttributes: true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    conservativeCollapse: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    keepClosingSlash: true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: ['*.html'],
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '.',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '../indexweb.html',
                        'components/**/*.html',
                        'assets/images/**/*.{png,gif,webp}',
                        'assets/fonts/*'
                    ],
                    rename: function (dest, src) {
                        return dest + "/" + src.replace('indexweb.html', 'dist/index.html'); 
                    }
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/assets/images',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/images',
                    src: [
                        'generated/*'
                    ]
                }]
            }

        },
        concurrent: {
            server: [],
            test: [],
            dist: [
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin'
            ]
        },
        karma: {
            unit: {
                configFile: '../../../test/javascript/karma.conf.js',
                singleRun: true
            }
        },
        cdnify: {
            dist: {
                html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
            }
        },
        ngAnnotate: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
                    src: '*.js',
                    dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
                }]
            }
        },
        ngconstant: {
            options: {
                name: 'rupcomApp',
                deps: false,
                wrap: '"use strict";\n
            },
            dev: {
                options: {
                    dest: 'app.constants.js'
                },
                constants: {
                    ENV: 'dev',
                    VERSION: parseVersionFromPomXml()
                }
            },
            prod: {
                options: {
                    dest: '.tmp/scripts/app/app.constants.js'
                },
                constants: {
                    ENV: 'prod',
                    VERSION: parseVersionFromPomXml()
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('serve', [
        'clean:server',
        'wiredep',
        'ngconstant:dev',
        'concurrent:server',
        'configureProxies',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
        grunt.task.run([target ? ('serve:' + target) : 'serve']);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', [
        'clean:server',
        'wiredep:test',
        'ngconstant:dev',
        'concurrent:test',
        'connect:test',
        'karma'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'wiredep:app',
        'ngconstant:prod',
        'useminPrepare',
        'ngtemplates',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'concat',
        'copy:dist',
        'ngAnnotate',
        'cssmin',
        'autoprefixer',
        'uglify',
        'rev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

Thanks in advance``

Cheers
Markus

Comment: Please provide details. What is your HTML like? Have you configured usemin targets? Where are you hitting a problem?

Comment: Please provide your gruntfile and your project structure.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I have added these things in my post